# Creating Daily toast notification in windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-phone-8.1, scheduled-tasks

I am working on Windows phone 8.1(not silverlight) using C# and I want to create a toast notification to display a content after every one hour(total 10 hour so 10 notification per day) and daily(10 * daily).
This is the code that I used to create notification

```html
public void ToastNotification()
        {
            ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

            XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");            
            toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Water to drink: "+ waterRemain));

          //  XmlNodeList toastImageAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
          //  ((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///assets/Info.png");
          //  ((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "Smiling Kidney");

            IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
            XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");

            audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-winsoundevent:Notification.IM");

            toastNode.AppendChild(audio);

            ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "{\"type\":\"toast\",\"param1\":\"12345\",\"param2\":\"67890\"}");

            Int16 startTimeInHours = 1;
            startTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(startTimeInHours);

            ScheduledToastNotification recurringToast = new ScheduledToastNotification(toastXml, startTime);
            recurringToast.Id = "Recurring_Toast";

            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(recurringToast);

        }
```

Now how can i make a toast notification daily and per day it should show 10 notifications?

Comment: Just wondering, if you are using scheduled toast notification you should be able to register 10 different notifications.

Comment: The range for number of times to repeat is from 1 to 5 only

Comment: Then 5 different notifications?